# Must not run with sudo while trying to create a runner using github-actions

Tags: ubuntu, github-actions

Hi I am new in github actions and I am trying to create a CICD pipline using Github action. I am using a digital ocean droplet UBUNTU 20.04 as my server and I am trying to create a runner as said in ->settings->actions

When I wrote the following command
 `./config.sh --url https://github.com/basobaasnepal/BasobaasWeb --token DFGFSDF234sf3fg45hd`

I got this:
Must not run with sudo

I tried to change the from root user to non root user but didn't work. I also tried `export {AGENT_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="1"}` but no luck there too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The env variable to use is `RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="1"`
You can :

- Export it before running config.sh using `export RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="1"`
- Start config.sh like this : `RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="1" ./config.sh --url...`

At the beginning of `config.sh` you can see the following test :

```sh
user_id=`id -u`
if [ $user_id -eq 0 -a -z "$RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT" ]; then
    echo "Must not run with sudo"
    exit 1
fi
```

`` user_id=`id -u` ``  : Gets the uid of the current user and store it to user_id.
`$user_id -eq 0` : Compare it with 0 (0 is the uid of root).
`-a -z "$RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT"` : `-a -z` Tests if the variable exists and is not empty.

So in our case we could do `RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="0"` or even `RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT="cool"` and it would work but `RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT=""` would not work.

I'm curious what was your issue when you tryed to run it as a non-root user ?

Comment: The issue when I tried to use non root user seems to be ownership of the file when I did chmod ubuntu ./config.sh then it worked. Your solution too worked can you give more insight why it worked? Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: I edited my post with an explaination, I hope it's clear :)

Comment: Awesome description, so removing the condition would work fine too. Do you  recommend doing that?

Comment: In general it's not a good practise to edit script provided by third parties. For example if you need to upgrade the runner you will download again the script and will have to modify it again. It's easier to play with the environment variable.